# C++: Overloaded New call constructs object automatically

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload the new operator in order to allocate my own memory, but I still need to construct the object.
That's why I decided to pass the parameters through a variadic template in order to feed the object's constructor properly.

The constructor is called twice in this example, I can't explain why.
It seems that the overloaded new calls automatically the constructor.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

class A
{
public:
  template<typename... Args>
  void *operator new(size_t sz, Args ...parameters)
  {
    void *mem = ::operator new(sizeof(A));
    A *var = ::new (mem) A(parameters...);
    return var;
  }
  A() : num(0) { std::cout << "Default" << std::endl; }
  A(int nb) : num(nb) { std::cout << "Integer = " << num << std::endl; }
  const int num;
};

int main()
{
  A *obj = new A(3);
  std::cout << "Obj result = " << obj->num << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `new A(3)` first calls `operator new()` to allocate memory, and then invokes the constructor for `A`. You need to remove `A *var = ::new (mem) A(parameters...);` . The purpose of arguments to `operator new` is only to help with allocation of memory.

Comment: Invoking `new` has actually two steps: 1) the allocating operator `new` (which you can override) and 2) the constructor call (which you can not prevent)

Comment: Hello, yes it seems it's being constructed on the void* I return.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed, there is not reason to try to call the constructor within the overload, the object will be constructed at returned void*'s pointed allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to overload the new operator in order to allocate my own memory, but I still need to construct the object.

No you don't. `operator new` by definition initializes the object. See [expr.new]/15:

> A *new-expression* that creates an object of type **T** initializes
>   that object as follows:
>
> — If the *new-initializer* is omitted, the object is
>   default-initialized (8.5); if no initialization is performed, the
>   object has indeterminate value.
>
> — Otherwise, the *new-initializer* is interpreted according to the
>   initialization rules of 8.5 for direct-initialization.

At a minimum, your overload can look like this:

```
void *operator new(size_t sz)
{
    return ::operator new(sizeof(A));
}
```

The `static` keyword is optional.